Xamarin.Forms NFC: Automatically Launch App and Read Tag Data on Android and iOS
I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms app where, upon placing an NFC card on the phone, the app should launch automatically and immediately read all tag data (ID and payload at least) in one cycle.
On some Android devices, the app launches as expected, but OnNewIntent in MainActivity is not triggered.  And it also starts my app without reading any data. So somehow the tag is not detected.
On other Android phones, the app doesn't launch at all when placing the NFC card on the device.
I'm using the following code adapted from this project but have made significant changes.
My first question is that how can I ensure reliable app launching and data reading across Android devices? Are there any modifications needed to make OnNewIntent trigger consistently?
My second question is about achieving the same behavior on iOS. Is it possible to start the app and read NFC data in a single cycle on iOS with Xamarin.Forms, considering iOS NFC limitations.

NativeNFCAdapterService

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NfcAdapter = Android.Nfc.NfcAdapter;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Nfc.Tech;
using Android.Nfc;
using Android.OS;
using NFCTestApp.Interfaces;
using NFCTestApp.Droid.Services;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using NFCTestApp.Droid.Enums;
using System.IO;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(NativeNFCAdapterService))]

namespace NFCTestApp.Droid.Services
{
    class NativeNFCAdapterService : INfcAdapter
    {
        private readonly MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)Platform.CurrentActivity;
        private Lazy<NfcAdapter> lazynfcAdapter = new Lazy<NfcAdapter>(() => NfcAdapter.GetDefaultAdapter(Platform.CurrentActivity));
        private NfcAdapter NfcAdapter => lazynfcAdapter.Value;
        private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        private IntentFilter[] writeTagFilters;
        private string[][] techList;
        private ReaderCallback readerCallback;

        public event Action<string> TagDiscovered;
        public event Action<string> AllDataRead;

        private NfcStatus NfcStatus => NfcAdapter == null ?
                                       NfcStatus.Unavailable : NfcAdapter.IsEnabled ?
                                       NfcStatus.Enabled : NfcStatus.Disabled;

        public static Tag DetectedTag { get; set; }

        public NativeNFCAdapterService()
        {
            Platform.ActivityStateChanged += Platform_ActivityStateChanged;
        }

        private void Platform_ActivityStateChanged(object sender, ActivityStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.State)
            {
                case ActivityState.Resumed:
                    EnableForegroundDispatch();
                    break;

                case ActivityState.Paused:
                    DisableForegroundDispatch();
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void ConfigureNfcAdapter()
        {
            IntentFilter tagdiscovered = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ActionTagDiscovered);
            IntentFilter ndefDiscovered = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ActionNdefDiscovered);
            IntentFilter techDiscovered = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ActionTechDiscovered);
            tagdiscovered.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
            ndefDiscovered.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
            techDiscovered.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);

            var intent = new Intent(mainActivity, mainActivity.Class).AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(mainActivity, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

            techList = new string[][]
            {
                new string[] { nameof(NfcA) },
                new string[] { nameof(NfcB) },
                new string[] { nameof(NfcF) },
                new string[] { nameof(NfcV) },
                new string[] { nameof(IsoDep) },
                new string[] { nameof(NdefFormatable) },
                new string[] { nameof(MifareClassic) },
                new string[] { nameof(MifareUltralight) },
            };

            readerCallback = new ReaderCallback();
            readerCallback.OnTagDiscoveredEvent += HandleTagDiscovered;

            writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagdiscovered, ndefDiscovered, techDiscovered };
        }

        public void DisableForegroundDispatch()
        {
            NfcAdapter?.DisableForegroundDispatch(Platform.CurrentActivity);
            NfcAdapter?.DisableReaderMode(Platform.CurrentActivity);
        }

        public void EnableForegroundDispatch()
        {
            if (pendingIntent == null || writeTagFilters == null || techList == null) { return; }

            NfcAdapter?.EnableForegroundDispatch(Platform.CurrentActivity, pendingIntent, writeTagFilters, techList);
            NfcAdapter?.EnableReaderMode(Platform.CurrentActivity, readerCallback, NfcReaderFlags.NfcA, null);

            Task.Run(async () => await ReadAllTagInfoAsync());
        }

        public void UnconfigureNfcAdapter()
        {
            Platform.ActivityStateChanged -= Platform_ActivityStateChanged;
        }

        public void HandleTagDiscovered(string tagId)
        {
            TagDiscovered?.Invoke(tagId);
        }

        public async Task SendAsync(byte[] bytes)
        {
            Ndef ndef = null;
            try
            {
                if (DetectedTag == null)
                    DetectedTag = await GetDetectedTag();

                ndef = Ndef.Get(DetectedTag);
                if (ndef == null) return;

                if (!ndef.IsWritable)
                {
                    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Tag is readonly", "Ok");
                    return;
                }

                if (!ndef.IsConnected)
                {
                    await ndef.ConnectAsync();
                }

                await WriteToTag(ndef, bytes);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Transmission error - possibly due to movement.", "Ok");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Request error", "Ok");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (ndef?.IsConnected == true) ndef.Close();
                ndef = null;
                DetectedTag = null;
            }
        }

        private async Task<Tag> GetDetectedTag()
        {
            mainActivity.NfcTag = new TaskCompletionSource<Tag>();
            readerCallback.NFCTag = new TaskCompletionSource<Tag>();
            var tagDetectionTask = await Task.WhenAny(mainActivity.NfcTag.Task, readerCallback.NFCTag.Task);
            return await tagDetectionTask;
        }

        private async Task WriteToTag(Ndef ndef, byte[] chunkedBytes)
        {
            var ndefRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TnfWellKnown, NdefRecord.RtdText?.ToArray(), Array.Empty<byte>(), chunkedBytes);
            NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(new[] { ndefRecord });
            ndef.WriteNdefMessage(message);
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("NFC", "Write Successful", "Ok");
        }

        public async Task<string> ReadAllTagInfoAsync()
        {
            if (DetectedTag == null)
            {
                DetectedTag = await GetDetectedTag();
            }

            var info = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            info.AppendLine("Tech List:");
            foreach (var tech in DetectedTag.GetTechList())
            {
                info.AppendLine($"- {tech}");
            }

            Ndef ndef = Ndef.Get(DetectedTag);
            if (ndef != null)
            {
                info.AppendLine("NDEF Supported: Yes");
                info.AppendLine($"NDEF Type: {ndef.Type}");
                info.AppendLine($"Is Writable: {ndef.IsWritable}");
                info.AppendLine($"Max Size: {ndef.MaxSize} bytes");

                var ndefMessage = ndef.CachedNdefMessage;
                if (ndefMessage != null && ndefMessage.GetRecords().Any())
                {
                    foreach (var ndefRecord in ndefMessage.GetRecords())
                    {
                        info.AppendLine($"Payload: {System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ndefRecord.GetPayload())}");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                info.AppendLine("NDEF Supported: No");
            }

            AllDataRead?.Invoke(info.ToString());

            return info.ToString();
        }
    }
}


ReaderCallback.cs

public class ReaderCallback : Java.Lang.Object, NfcAdapter.IReaderCallback
{
    public TaskCompletionSource<Tag> NFCTag { get; set; }
    public event Action<string> OnTagDiscoveredEvent;

    public void OnTagDiscovered(Tag tag)
    {
        var isSuccess = NFCTag?.TrySetResult(tag);
        if (NFCTag == null || !isSuccess.Value)
            NativeNFCAdapterService.DetectedTag = tag;

        byte[] tagIdBytes = tag.GetId();
        string tagId = BitConverter.ToString(tagIdBytes).Replace("-", "");
        OnTagDiscoveredEvent?.Invoke(tagId);
    }
}


MainActivity.cs

[MetaData(NfcAdapter.ActionTechDiscovered, Resource = "@xml/nfc_tech_filter")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { NfcAdapter.ActionTechDiscovered }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "text/plain")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { NfcAdapter.ActionNdefDiscovered }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "text/plain")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { NfcAdapter.ActionTagDiscovered }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "text/plain")]
[Activity(Label = "NFCTestApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    public TaskCompletionSource<Tag> NfcTag { get; set; }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("It is here");
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);

        Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("NFC Tag Discovered", "A1", "OK");
        });
    }
}


AndroidManifest.xml

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="NFCTestApp.Droid">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <application android:label="NFCTestApp" android:icon="@mipmap/icon">
        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </application>
</manifest>

here is the card info

EDIT: nfc_tech_filter.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
  </tech-list>
</resources>


NFC card What kind off NFC card is that? NDEF? also that code looks familiar for some reason

@FreakyAli it is NDEF and yes I think it is from your project (I already gave the link in the question). I just changed some parts of the code. Maybe you can help me more than anyone else here.
Basically I need to start my app with an nfc card and read data in the first cycle of detection. I have added IntentFilters in the MainActivity as attributes but I realise that you have also added Intents in the Adapter class. I think it is redundant for me. Anyway, it did not work on my Android phone, which has Android 9. The one that works has Android 12. That might be the reason.

@FreakyAli the second issue is that OnNewIntent is never triggered

NDEF is not a type of NFC card, it is a data format for storing data on a number of different types of NFC Tags. It would help if you specified the make and model of the NFC Tag. There are Apps like "Tag Info" from NXP that can determine the hardware of a lot of types of NFC Tags, use that to tell us if you don't know the answer.

@Andrew I did not know that they are different things. I've just updated my question. You can see a sample card info.

Good, the Tag is a Fully NFC Compliant NTAG213, not a non standard Mifare Classic Tag (which not all phones read), so this eliminates that problem.

@Andrew basic issues are
1- OnNewIntent is never triggered
2- But the NFC tag launches my app on my android v12 phone but it does not on the other phone that has android v9

Try using just one of the Search functionalities, instead of using both ForegroundDispatch and ReaderMode

@FreakyAli I use only ReaderMode but it did not solve my problem.

Try just using one of the two at once and see if that works for the new intent because, Reader Mode won't call new intent

@FreakyAli you are right, I just used EnableForegroundDispatch, new intent worked but when the app is open. If the app is in the background or completly closed, the intent is not triggered (I put a an alert dialog). It only works when the app is open.

So did you find a solution in the end?

@FreakyAli yes but not with the intents. If you checkout your github proojects,you will see you'll not get intents. It comes only when the app is on top. Even though the intent's action is null.

@FreakyAli I have not yet testet, but can I launch the app in ios like android?

The short answer is no

@FreakyAli thank you for your answers. Actually I made it. So I can launch my app with a NFC card in ios and android

How, please show me as well if possible

@FreakyAli actually it was very easy to do that. There are two ways to do. One is universal links and another one is custom url schemes (or deep link). For the first option, you need a url and an apple-app-site-association file. And for the second one you just write CFBundleURLTypes into the infoplist.
And then write the tag url (for the first option: mywebsite.com/nfc-launch?id=parmeter1&data=parameter2 and for the second option: nfctestapp://nfc-launch?id=... ). When I scan the tag on iphone (must be XS or later iphones), the safari is opened and ask me to open my app.

Would love to see a Github Example of how you achieved it

Update
Now that the nfc_tech_filter.xml has been upload it show the real problem.
Each tech element in tech-list element is additive.
And as you list all tech type in on tech-list then it technically impossible for a single tag to be a technology types at once as some of them are incompatible with each other.
This is explained in the documentation but unfortunately first example in the documentation is wrong (I have raised a documentation bug with Google on this). The later examples are right.
So you nfc_tech_filter.xml would be better like as you are looking for Ndef on a NTAG215
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <tech-list>
    <!--Match all these techs -->
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    <!--AND -->
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
  </tech-list>
  <!--OR -->
  <tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
  </tech-list>
</resources>

There are two other possible problems, starting an App via manifest filters can deliver then Intent notification to one of two possible code locations, OnNewIntent is one but it can also be delivered just to the main Activity instead.
This is because there are various other factors affecting where the Intent is delivered.
From the Android Documentation:-

This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent). In either case, when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it.

The main words here are "re-launched"
So if you want to start your app via NFC then you should also check the Intent that the Main Activity was passed when it was started.
You do this by calling getIntent() in the main activity when it starts, this is usually done in onCreate. Then you would getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG) on this Intent to see if the initial Intent contained Data about the NFC Tag (You would null check the return of getParcelableExtra)
If you are only interested in NDEF data the you could use NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES instead of the raw Tag as long as you have not turned of the parsing of NDEF by the NFC System Service.
This leads to a second possible problem.
Your code seems to use both the EnableForegroundDispatch and it's newer and better replacement EnableReaderMode. Your code should only use one or the other with EnableReaderMode being the better one to use. Under various different conditions this could mean that the ReaderCallback could be called instead of onNewIntent().
I would remove all the code related to EnableForegroundDispatch

thank you for your reply. Sorry for the late reply. I was sick for a few days and did not work.
Well, when I saw your answer I removed the EnableForegroundDispatch part but still the OnNewIntent method was not triggered.
I think the problem comes from the IntentFilters. Maybe I should define them in the manifest. But then I have another issues..

Did you also getIntent() in onCreate? Also you don't show the content of @xml/nfc_tech_filter file as you can specify the technologies so that no Tag would ever match.

Yes, I get Intent in onCreate, here is my code
https://i.imgur.com/vEbrAW3.png
When the app is completely closed or it is in the background then I get the NFD_DISCOVERED intent in onCreate method.  As I realise that OnNewIntent is only triggered when the app is open and visible.

but the intent in the OnNewIntent method is kind of null. intent.Action is null so I cannot get the Tag from the intent by using GetParcelableExtra.

Sounds like the @xml/nfc_tech_filter file contents might be wrong, but you have not edited your question to show it's contents.

thank you for your reply. I've added nfc_tech_filter.xml content to my question.

Answer updated with a correct nfc_tech_filter.xml example.

Thank you for your answer @Andrew. But it did not help me. I think I should create a clean project and apply them step by step

In my app I just have <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech> listed as I don't use Ndef on NTAG 215's (though mine is a Java App) and that works fine on all tested devices.

https://blog.stackademic.com/nfc-ndef-communication-with-maui-and-xamarin-forms-fae28632c2d3
here is also the article that I follow. I think there are some issue there.
is it possible to share your test app? I can compare it with mine

It's not possible for me to share my App's java code. The only other thing I can see wrong in the given code is PendingIntentFlags.Immutable should be PendingIntentFlags.Mutable but you've probably already removed that as it's related to EnableForegroundDispatch

I see, I think I've solved the issue in another way. I dont need intents. Because I can read the NFC in the OnCreate method and when the tag is available OnTagDiscovered method is triggered. So I can the tags when the app is closed or in background or active. I'll test for ios tomorrow :)) Thank you for your help

iOS is a whole different problem as it handles NFC quite differently and not something I do.

I guess so :D But can I lauch the app like Android? I cannot continue to develop because  the boos must agree the apple developer license agreement. ios will be a headache

Yes it can but done by a universal link on the Tag from memory.

thank you. I am working on it now. But FreakyAli wrote a comment in my question:  "The short answer is no " :))
but I'll search what you wrote. As I understand, I have to write something on the tag

Yes on iOS you have to write a URL record to the Tag, sort of like an Android AAR Record.

I see. I'll try that and write my feedback. Thank you a lot for your help

You are great, I did it! :D I wrote a URL to the tag and added associated domains, and it launches my app (though the user has to tap the notification). The URL also contains an ID (a tag ID, and I can include other necessary info in the URL like abc.com/nft-launch?id=1234&data=boss). When the app is visible, I read the data immediatly. Thank you so much for your help. By the way, the plugin on https://github.com/franckbour/Plugin.NFC for Xamarin already supports launching apps on Android. Just change the MIME type and press the "write tag (custom)" button.

And I made it with deep link :)) now I don't need a url. It seems easier and better
